# Drupal 7 Omega - js file not working

Tags: javascript, theming

Okay so I have a headache trying to figure this one out. I am working in Drupal 7 with the Omega theme. Trying to get a js file to work.

I have a js file that is set up through the .info file and is showing in view source. The file contents are below. I can get this to work when I place in the wysiwyg on the page however it won't work when I set it up properly as a .js file.

```
 (function ($) {  
// All your code here
  $('#block-menu-menu ul.menu').removeClass('menu').addClass('sub-menu');

// Create the dropdown base
  $("<select />").appendTo(".menu");

  // Create default option "Go to..."
  $("<option />", {
     "selected": "selected",
     "value"   : "",
     "text"    : "Go to..."
  }).appendTo(".menu select");

  // Populate dropdown with  items
  $(".menu a").each(function() {
   var el = $(this);
   $("<option />", {
       "value"   : el.attr("href"),
       "text"    : el.text()
   }).appendTo(".menu select");
  });

  $(".menu select").change(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
  });

})(jQuery);
```

My issue is it works when placed in the page, but when I place in the .js file and call it through .info it won't work. Again the file shows up in the view source so it is there. I have to be missing something. NOTE * I am not a developer.

Any thoughts?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your javascript in a Drupal Behaviors handler. You can read the [Javascript Documentation](http://drupal.org/node/756722) for more information (scroll down and look for the heading "Behaviors").

Basically, your code will end up looking something like this:

```
    (function ($) {  

      Drupal.behaviors.exampleBehavior = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {            
         // All your code here
       }
     };

   })(jQuery);
```

If this does not solve your issue, you use check your site for any javascript error messages and update your original post to include them. The way I recommend to do this is to install the [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) plugin for Firefox and open up the Error Console (tools -> web developer -> error console) and look for messages highlighted in red.